# Display data in specific format using SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have data in current format

[image]

and I want to get data through SQL query in

[image]

Can some one explain what should I search or how can I write SQL query with this. I'm not an expert in SQL.

Comment: Please add your sample data. Adding Image as data in Stackoverflow is not a good idea.

Comment: You will need to use [PIVOT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: how can i add sample data , and @Squirrel i dont have dynamic data so how can i write name of columns as date can be change

Comment: One step at a time. First you get the `PIVOT` query working, then you work on changing it to a `Dynamic` Query using [sp_executesql](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-executesql-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Answer (score 1):

You need dynamic pivot query to achieve this. try below query

```
declare @columns varchar(max)='',@sql nvarchar(max);

Create table #temp (Name nvarchar(max));

insert into #temp select distinct date from YourTable --inert distinct date for pivot column

SELECT @columns+=QUOTENAME(Name) + ',' from #temp
SET @columns = LEFT(@columns, LEN(@columns) - 1);

set @sql='
SELECT *  FROM   
(
 select ID,cast(Status as int) Status,date from YourTable
) t 
PIVOT(Max(Status)
FOR date IN ('+@columns+')
) AS pivot_table
'

EXEC (@Sql)

Drop Table #temp
```

Comment: as status is bit column so i am getting this error 
Operand data type bit is invalid for max operator.

Comment: Ok just use cast to int like `Max(cast(Status as int))` .

Comment: I have edited my answer. on select use `cast(Status as int) Status`

Comment: What's the `#temp` for, you can just do a normal `select`. Also you shouldn't use `SELECT @columns+=` to aggregate, it's behaviour can be unstable. Instead use `STRING_AGG` or `FOR XML`

Comment: Here #temp is for dynamic column name. I am getting distinct date from original table to #temp then setting @columns variable with all the column for `dynamic pivot`. And I am using older version of `sql-server` so `String_AGG` does not support in my version. But `String_AGG` is best option for upgraded version.

Comment: Again, why can you not just do `SELECT @columns+=QUOTENAME(date) + ',' from (select distinct date from YourTable) t` no need for a temp table. Better, use the `FOR XML` version as I said: `SET @columns = STUFF((SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME(date) from (select distinct date from YourTable) t FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('text()[1]','nvarchar(max)'), 1, 1, '');`

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I will follow next time.